# Drag and Drop with Protractor in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, protractor

I appreciate there's quite a bit of stuff already been said about automating drag and drop as part of E2E testing. However after many, many hours of fiddling around, I cannot get any of the methods described to work...that is using Functions, coordinates etc etc. Oddly enough, console.log maintains the tests have passed, but the screenshots clearly show nothing has happened.
[Screenshots shows a portion of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lURrc.png)

The user selects a paper and drags onto the image. As the drag 'starts' the grey overlay on the image clears and the paper is rendered on the room.

The code snippet shows one of the more simple ideas I've tried and I would be very pleased to receive any help going!

```
const JS_HTML5_DND = 'function e(e,t,n,i){var r=a.createEvent("DragEvent");r.initMouseEvent(t,!0,!0,o,0,0,0,c,g,!1,!1,!1,!1,0,null),Object.defineProperty(r,"dataTransfer",{get:function(){return d}}),e.dispatchEvent(r),o.setTimeout(i,n)}var t=arguments[0],n=arguments[1],i=arguments[2]||0,r=arguments[3]||0;if(!t.draggable)throw new Error("Source element is not draggable.");var a=t.ownerDocument,o=a.defaultView,l=t.getBoundingClientRect(),u=n?n.getBoundingClientRect():l,c=l.left+(l.width>>1),g=l.top+(l.height>>1),s=u.left+(u.width>>1)+i,f=u.top+(u.height>>1)+r,d=Object.create(Object.prototype,{_items:{value:{}},effectAllowed:{value:"all",writable:!0},dropEffect:{value:"move",writable:!0},files:{get:function(){return this._items.Files}},types:{get:function(){return Object.keys(this._items)}},setData:{value:function(e,t){this._items[e]=t}},getData:{value:function(e){return this._items[e]}},clearData:{value:function(e){delete this._items[e]}},setDragImage:{value:function(e){}}});if(n=a.elementFromPoint(s,f),!n)throw new Error("The target element is not interactable and need to be scrolled into the view.");u=n.getBoundingClientRect(),e(t,"dragstart",101,function(){var i=n.getBoundingClientRect();c=i.left+s-u.left,g=i.top+f-u.top,e(n,"dragenter",1,function(){e(n,"dragover",101,function(){n=a.elementFromPoint(c,g),e(n,"drop",1,function(){e(t,"dragend",1,callback)})})})})';


describe('Drag and Drop Test', function() {
it('should drag', function () {



    var e1 = element(by.xpath('html/body/webapp-app/div/div/webapp-johnlewis-visualiser/div/div[2]/div/digitalbridge-shortlist/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/img'));
    var e2 = element(by.css('.db-project-designer'));

    element(by.xpath('html/body/webapp-app/div/div/webapp-johnlewis-visualiser/div/div[2]/div/digitalbridge-shortlist/div/div/ul/li[1]/a/img')).click();
    //element(by.xpath('html/body/webapp-app/div/div/webapp-johnlewis-visualiser/div/div[1]/div/div/digitalbridge-project/div/digitalbridge-project-designer/canvas')).click();

    browser.driver.actions().dragAndDrop(e1.getWebElement(),e2.getWebElement()).perform();

    browser.sleep(2000);
});
});
```

The constant is showing an error `'const' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz). (W104)` - I do have ES6 installed in Node_Modules.

I inserted the `click` line to see if pre-selecting the item made any difference...it didn't!

Thank you

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this library https://github.com/SunGard-Labs/sg-protractor-tools

The library also includes functions that simplify common tasks like

Scrolling to an element
Drag and drop
Waiting for DOM elements to become visible or hidden

Comment: My colleagues in DEV have told me they use Dragula for all D+D activity in the this app. As anyone managed to link Dragula to Protractor I wonder?

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = function simulateDragAndDrop(sourceNode, destinationNode) {
    const EVENT_TYPES = {
        DRAG_END: 'dragend',
        DRAG_START: 'dragstart',
        DROP: 'drop'
    };

    function createCustomEvent(type) {
        const event = new CustomEvent('CustomEvent');
        event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null);
        event.dataTransfer = {
            data: {
            },
            setData: function(type, val) {
                this.data[type] = val;
            },
            getData: function(type) {
                return this.data[type];
            }
        };
        return event;
    }

    function dispatchEvent(node, type, event) {
        if (node.dispatchEvent) {
            return node.dispatchEvent(event);
        }
        if (node.fireEvent) {
            return node.fireEvent('on' + type, event);
        }
    }

    const event = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START);
    dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START, event);

    const dropEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DROP);
    dropEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
    dispatchEvent(destinationNode, EVENT_TYPES.DROP, dropEvent);

    const dragEndEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END);
    dragEndEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer;
    dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END, dragEndEvent);
}
```

You can call it from you code like this

```
browser.executeScript(dragAndDrop, element, targetArea);
```

Comment: Thanks andriyze. Sadly cannot use this function as I get `'const' is available in ES6 (use 'esversion: 6') or Mozilla JS extensions (use moz). (W104)`

Comment: you can use 'var' instead of 'const' or 'let'